# При попытке скачать любую библиотеку выдает Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/2b/43/c86538ae1a81308768cd2fc362c02d808cb99274fb502e2dd9f30ade6ce9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4.tar.gz (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)))

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\bubunduc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

[image: Ручная установка библиотек не помогла]
Ручная установка библиотек не помогла

Comment: лучше вставлять сообщение об ошибке текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: У Вас скорее всего проблемы с сетью (файрвол? провайдер? и тд). Попробуйте сделать трассировку возможно будет видно где проблема: `tracert files.pythonhosted.org`. P.S. sudo под виндой сильно ))

Comment: Перенесите текст вывода из консоли в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: В последней команде вы адрес прокси откуда-то скопировали, или у вас интернет через прокси работает?

Comment: скопировал из интернета

Comment: Во-первых sudo не будет работать на windows. Просто уберите эту часть команды. Во-вторых часть с proxy будет работать, только если у вас запущен прокси сервер, и он работает именно на localhost и на 3128 порту (скорее всего нет). А вообще, такое впечатление, что РКН шалит: https://files.pythonhosted.org не открывается в браузере без включенного VPN. Хотя сайта в реестрах вроде нет, ни по домену, ни по ip.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
1. python -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: ничего из этого не помогет,пробовал

Comment: Тогда похоже у вас что-то неправильно настроено в файерволе/прокси

Comment: я там ничего не менял, все настройки по умолчанию win 10